# Question about "Unused memory allocated to .net" in combination with "gcserver ebnabled=true"

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I do have an application server written in c# (.net 4.8) and i try to understand the memory usage.
I think there is no problem with my memory (no memory leak), but i'd like to understand the behavior when using **gcserver ebnabled=true** in the app.config.

The following are screenshots of the memory consumption taken with ANTS.

## Memory after server start (gcserver enabled=true)

[image]

## Memory after login/logout 1200 times (gcserver enabled=true)

[image]

## Memory after server start (gcserver enabled=false)

[image]

## Memory after login/logout 1200 times (gcserver enabled=false)

[image]

## My current assumption and question

When using **gcserver ebnabled=true**, a lot of unused memory is allocated.
I assume this is for performance reasons and also because my system has plenty of memory left (At the time of those screenshots, my system used 14gb of available 32gb).

Is there some documentation about this behavior and why so much unused memory is allocated`when **gcserver ebnabled=true** is used?

Comment: Reading [this MSDN documentation on gcserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element) it appears that on multiprocessor systems, the runtime will allocate one heap PER PROCESSOR, whereas on a workstation (gserver = false) it will only use a single one. What kind of processor configuration do you have on the system you tested on ?

Comment: I have an Intel I9-12900 (12 core)

Comment: Matches the doc, 118Mo *12 cores = 1.4Go total. We probably don't see this at the start because the heap is still quite young and nothing expanded it yet ?

Comment: I think this explains it. But i was unable to find this explanation on the mentioned msdn article. Is it only implied that in this case each processor gets it own heap or did i miss the explicit documentation?

Comment: It's in the gcserver configuration section, the one for GCNoAffinitize

Comment: Thanks. You might add this as as a replay, then i'd set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [this MSDN documentation on the gcserver setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element), and particularly in the configuration section for `GCNoAffinitize`

When enabled, one of the effects of the gcserver setting is to have one heap per processor (read here : by processor core), which would explain the observed behaviour based on the hardware reported.

In our case 118Mo (Heap with gcserver disabled) * 12 cores = 1.4Go, which is matching the observed difference between the two captured states.